# Cannot get the active cell's value of DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in c#. 
I have a datagridview with some checkbox column. I want to insert checkbox value to database as "Y"(if checkbox checked) and "N"(if checkbox unchecked). So I have written this code.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow Rw in dgv.Rows)
                        {
                            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(InsertQuery, Con))
                            {
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableId", Rw.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TableName", Rw.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Parent", Rw.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", Rw.Cells[3].Value.ToString());
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sr", Rw.Cells[4].Value.ToString());
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@View", (Convert.ToBoolean(Rw.Cells[5].Value) == false ? "N".Trim() : "Y".Trim()));
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Save", (Convert.ToBoolean(Rw.Cells[6].Value) == false ? "N".Trim() : "Y".Trim()));
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Update", (Convert.ToBoolean(Rw.Cells[7].Value) == false ? "N".Trim() : "Y".Trim()));
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Delete", (Convert.ToBoolean(Rw.Cells[8].Value) == false ? "N".Trim() : "Y".Trim()));
                                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                            }
                        }
```

It's working fine too, but it's not reading the value of current cell (which I checked or unchecked)
What I am missing ?

Comment: Looping thru a DGV to insert or update rows means you should read up on DataBinding.  You can do all that in one line of code.

Comment: @WelcomeOverflow Thank you for your response. Can you please elaborate ?
I am using MS-Access database.